# 2-4 Tree Max/Min number of nodes

Tags: data-structures, tree

I'm trying to learn about 2-4 trees and came across a question I have no idea about, and google hasn't been very helpful either. What is the maximum and minimum number of nodes for a 2-4 tree?

Answer (score 0):

2-3-4 trees (same as 2-4 tree) are essentially B-trees of order 4, the minimum number of nodes is 1 and the maximum... well, how much data do you wish to store in one? Check out the link for more info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933%E2%80%934_tree

EDIT: P.S. Google is your friend and sorry for reactivating a dead post...